# What would be a more formal way of saying "do a lot of teaching"?

Tags: word-choice, formal-language, formality

I want to say that lecturers at our faculty do a lot of teaching, but to my ears, this phrasing is rather informal – am I right? So, what would be a more formal (or at least less informal) way of saying this? I've tried exchanging the verb and/or the NP with more formal alternatives, but they just don't seem to work very well together. For instance, *conduct much teaching* or *perform a great deal of teaching* just sounds weird...

As always, any help I can get would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Our faculty lecturers spend most of their time teaching.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks – not quite what I need to say though, since this doesn't stress the amount of teaching per se, only how much it is in relation to other things. See what I mean?  "Our faculty lecturers spend most of their time teaching" could just as well mean that they don't work very hard, but to the extent that they do work, most of their work is teaching, right? It's a very fine difference obviously, but still. Thanks for your suggestion though!

Comment: I must say, I can't think of any situation in which "do a lot of teaching" would be inappropriate for being too informal.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Oh, ok! Great! I'll go with that then :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Our lecturers at our faculty ***put much time and effort into teaching*** ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/put-sth-into-sth-doing-sth))

is definitely more formal than *do a lot of teaching*. I always prefer ***much*** to ***a lot of*** in formal written texts. Actually [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/lots-a-lot-plenty) shows that:

> We use ***lots, a lot*** and ***plenty*** in **informal** styles to talk about quantities, amounts and degree. ***Lots*** and ***a lot*** are similar in meaning to ***much*** and ***many***. ***Plenty*** means ‘enough’ or ‘more than enough’. ***Lots*** is even more informal than ***a lot***:

DO is indeed used as a main verb to talk about taking part in activities:

> I did a lot of hiking and mountain-climbing when I was younger. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/do))

You can do teaching, gardening and so on, but it is not the most formal way of speaking of a profession.